# camel Atomikos XA continually reconecting

Tags: apache-camel, jms, jta, xa, atomikos

I have recently moved my routes over to use XA, I am not sure if this is normal behavior or a problem but I am seeing continual reconnecting in the log and the transaction logs are growing when there is no activity as such on the jms queue.

The logs show the following

```
16:14:19.777 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XAResourceTransaction-logInfo - XAResource.start ( 31302E3136322E3230382E3130322E746D30303030323030303032:31302E3136322E3230382E3130322E746D32 , XAResource.TMNOFLAGS ) on resource ConnectionFactoryTESTQM represented by XAResource instance com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiXAResource@27520e8f
16:14:20.806 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJmsXaSessionProxy-logInfo - atomikos xa session proxy for resource ConnectionFactoryTESTQM: calling getTransacted on JMS driver session...
16:14:20.806 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJmsMessageConsumerProxy-logInfo - atomikos MessageConsumer proxy for com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueReceiver@690215c4: close...
16:14:20.822 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XAResourceTransaction-logInfo - XAResource.end ( 31302E3136322E3230382E3130322E746D30303030323030303032:31302E3136322E3230382E3130322E746D32 , XAResource.TMSUCCESS ) on resource ConnectionFactoryTESTQM represented by XAResource instance com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiXAResource@27520e8f
16:14:20.838 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJmsXaSessionProxy-logInfo - atomikos xa session proxy for resource ConnectionFactoryTESTQM: closing session atomikos xa session proxy for resource ConnectionFactoryTESTQM - is terminated ? false
16:14:20.838 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJmsConnectionProxy-logInfo - atomikos connection proxy for resource ConnectionFactoryTESTQM: close()...
16:14:20.838 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp-logInfo - commit() done (by application) of transaction 10.162.208.102.tm0000200002
16:14:20.978 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XAResourceTransaction-logInfo - XAResource.commit ( 31302E3136322E3230382E3130322E746D30303030323030303032:31302E3136322E3230382E3130322E746D32 , true ) on resource ConnectionFactoryTESTQM represented by XAResource instance com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiXAResource@27520e8f
16:14:21.009 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.icatch.imp.BaseTransactionManager-logInfo - createCompositeTransaction ( 300000 ): created new ROOT transaction with id 10.162.208.102.tm0000300002
16:14:21.009 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean-logInfo - AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'ConnectionFactoryTESTQM': createConnection()...
16:14:21.009 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean-logInfo - AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'ConnectionFactoryTESTQM': init...
16:14:21.009 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJmsConnectionProxy-logInfo - atomikos connection proxy for resource ConnectionFactoryTESTQM: creating XA-capable session...
16:14:21.134 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJmsConnectionProxy-logInfo - atomikos connection proxy for resource ConnectionFactoryTESTQM: calling hashCode on JMS driver...
16:14:21.134 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJmsConnectionProxy-logInfo - atomikos connection proxy for resource ConnectionFactoryTESTQM: calling hashCode on JMS driver...
16:14:21.134 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJmsConnectionProxy-logInfo - atomikos connection proxy for resource ConnectionFactoryTESTQM: calling start on JMS driver...
16:14:21.134 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJmsXaSessionProxy-logInfo - atomikos xa session proxy for resource ConnectionFactoryTESTQM: calling createQueue on JMS driver session...
16:14:21.134 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJmsXaSessionProxy-logInfo - atomikos xa session proxy for resource ConnectionFactoryTESTQM: calling createConsumer on JMS driver session com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXASession@41a4d0d0
16:14:21.150 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJmsMessageConsumerProxy-logInfo - atomikos MessageConsumer proxy for com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueReceiver@3cb81a5f: receive ( 1000 )...
16:14:21.150 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosJmsMessageConsumerProxy-logInfo - atomikos MessageConsumer proxy for com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueReceiver@3cb81a5f: receive ( 1000 , null )...
16:14:21.150 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp-logInfo - registerSynchronization ( com.atomikos.jms.ConsumerProducerSupport$JmsRequeueSynchronization@4d70e77 ) for transaction 10.162.208.102.tm0000300002
16:14:21.150 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[AAA.TESTQ1]] INFO  com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp-logInfo - addParticipant ( XAResourceTransaction: 31302E3136322E3230382E3130322E746D30303030333030303032:31302E3136322E3230382E3130322E746D33 ) for transaction 10.162.208.102.tm0000300002
```

If this is normal then I will just surpress the logging but I figured it worth checking.

thanks
Paul